# Uniform convergence of $\{\tanh(nx)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Quick question. How can I prove that the sequence of functions:

\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=\{\tanh(nx)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}
\end{equation}

converges uniformly to:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} -1, & x<0 \\
 1, & x> 0 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

and why the sequence:

\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=\{\frac{1}{2}\left(\tanh(nx)+1\right)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}
\end{equation}

does not converge uniformly but only pointwise to:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, & x<0 \\
 1/2, & x=0 \\
1, & x>0\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Shouldn't it converge to $0$ at $x=0$ (since $\tanh(0) = 0$)?

Comment: @CameronWilliams And it doesn't converge uniformly.

Comment: @AlexR Quite right! I was starting to doubt myself since, as you answered, the uniform limit of continuous functions is again continuous.

Comment: @AlexR So it does converge to $f(x)=sgn(x)$ but not uniformly. Is that right?

Comment: @Mitscaype Yes, as you can see with proof from my answer.

Comment: Correct! I had to refresh. Alright thank you for your time! Can I bother you for another 2'? The question I posted is part of another question I am dealing with atm. If $\{tanh(nx)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ does not converge uniformly to $sgn(x)$, then is it still possible that the sequence of distributions $\langle T_{f_n},\phi(x)\rangle$ to converge to the correspoding distribution $\langle T_f,\phi(x)\rangle$ of $sgn(x)$?

Comment: I am asking that, since uniform converge is required for the above to hold. If uniform convergence is not satisfied then what happens? Sorry for these questions, I know that it is not part of the original question, and you do not have to answer that. But I felt I could ask you. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mitscaype I suggest you ask that as a separate question, but convergence in distribution is weaker than uniform convergence. Your sequence does converge in distribution.

Comment: Alright, once again thank you! I will post it as a separate question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first claim is false, in fact $\tanh nx \to \mathrm{sgn} x$ pointwise (with $\mathrm{sgn}(0) := 0$). Since $\tanh nx$ is continuous for all $n$ and $\mathrm{sgn}$ is not, the convergence can't be uniform.

Similarly, the second claim follows from limit arithmetics,
$$\frac12 (1+\tanh nx) \to \frac12 (1+ \mathrm{sgn}(x)) = \theta(x)$$
(the latter is the Heaviside step function)

The non-uniformness can also be seen by looking at the sequence $x_n = \frac1n$. Computing $f_n(x_n) = \tanh \frac nn = \tanh 1 \ne 0$, but uniform convergence would then imply $0 = f(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_n) = \tanh 1$, a contradiction.

Proving the point-wise convergence is rather simple, noting that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \tanh x = \pm 1$ and $\tanh 0 = 0$ we get it basically for free:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \tanh nx = \begin{cases} \lim_{y\to-\infty} \tanh y \qquad = -1 & x < 0 \\ \tanh 0 \qquad\qquad\quad\ \ \ \, = 0 & x = 0\\ \lim_{y\to\infty} \tanh y \qquad\ \  = 1 & y > 0 \end{cases} = \mathrm{sgn}(x)$$